# How to use react-gtm-module in react js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In my react app I used `react-gtm-module`. and I have GTM ID only.

I put the below code in each page router component

```
import TagManager from 'react-gtm-module';

componentDidMount(){
        const tagManagerArgs = {
            dataLayer: {
                page: '/pagepath'
            },
            gtmId: 'GTM-XXXXXX',
            
        }
        TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs)
       
    }
```

I just put the above code in each route component. By using the above code, in google analytics sometimes the path shows and sometimes not showing in `Active Page`.

Is it only code I have to put in my code to achieve google analytics track pages or I have to add more else? If yes then exactly what I have to add and where to add?

Definitely, I miss something in my code. But what exactly?

Comment: Is it necessary to send the page path? Doesn't GTM always automatically send that info?

Answer (score 13):

Initialise with just the id in each app, not each page

```
TagManager.initialize({
  gtmId: gtm_id,
});
```

and then in each page,

```
TagManager.dataLayer({
  dataLayer: {
    event: 'pageview',
    pagePath: 'page-path-here',
    pageTitle: 'page-title-here',
  },
});
```