# Why isn't the GTM data layer in React website appearing in Google Analytics?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have used [react-gtm-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gtm-module) to implement Universal Analytics tracking on a multi-page React application/website.

The data is coming through to Google Analytics, but the data layer is not and I'm hoping someone can help me identify why.

## **GTM Preview mode**

I can see that when the container is loaded, all of the data layer values are set to the default value of 'Unknown'. This is what is passed through to Google Analytics.

[image]

However, when the Window is loaded, the data layer is populated with values. This is not being sent through to Google Analytics.

[image]

How do I push the data layer through to Google Analytics at the correct moment, once the data is available?

Many thanks,

Katie

Answer (score 3):

Hi since you mention that you are using react-gtm-module there were different method to add data layer in your code. you need to read this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gtm-module#datalayer.

i have used it.
i will give you example for it.

if you want to add data layer on specific click event.

1. first you need to write datalayer code in you web app.like this
   [follow for add data in data layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66829452/how-to-use-react-gtm-module-in-react-js-app)
2. second step is to verify you data is push to your data layer or not.
   for that got to your browser console and write datalayer.
   then it's big data set you need to find your event name and check in there your
   data is there or not.
3. also you need to make variables according your data.[follow step 2 to do this step](https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2021/04/06/tracking-single-page-applications-google-analytics-4/).
4. in this you need to verify it on your preview mode of GTM. after if you want to access that data in GA you need to make custom event trigger in GTM and add it in your Event tag you also need to add event parameters in event tag.

for access data in GA you can follow this video also[follow for how to get data in GA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PV3KBpbKXsA)

Note : for data layer push you have only this solution what i share. because you use  that react-gtm-module.

Answer (score 0):

The values are only sent to Google Analytics when there is a 'hit' to be sent. A datalayer.push (when you insert values into the datalyer) is not considered a hit, thus no data will be available.

You have some options here.

The best scenario would be to insert the values into the datalayer before the GTM is even loaded on the website. That would guarantee that all your hits would have the data available, and you would not need to delay any hits.

If that is not possible, you can also change your datalayer.push implementation to include an 'event' parameter, and then use that as a condition on the Google Analytics tag. Something like this:

```js
dataLayer.push({
  'event': 'dataLayerLoaded',
  'environment': env,
  'isAdminUser': isAdmin,
  ...
})
```

You can then create an event trigger that fires on the event 'dataLayerLoaded', and use this trigger on the Google Analytics Page View tag instead of the normal 'page view' one.

If you choose to follow this last route, be aware that this event will need to fire every time, otherwise no data will be sent at all. Also, if you have any custom events implemented, you may have to change their logic you use to take into consideration this new approach.

EDIT: It is also possible to change your Google Analytics Page View Trigger to "Window Loaded", but you'll need to be sure that the datalayer will always load before that, otherwise you will lose information.